# Handle all Oracle ORA errors using a custom function

Tags: sql, oracle, hide

We are using a middle ware technology to build a web application. During security audit, an issue was raised that the application is exposing ORA codes generated by Oracle in case of an oracle error (Like Constraint Validation error or Unique Key Constraint error).

We cannot change the middle ware code to hide the errors at code level, so would like to know if we can write a common handler function in Oracle which can act as an interceptor where I can try to strip the ORA code off the error and raise another one.

Comment: It depends on what technology you're using for your web application. It needs to be coded to handle ORA errors whenever it calls the database.

Answer (score 0):

In PL/SQL, you can catch exceptions and raise other ones (this works for all PL/SQL code, stored procedures, function, packages, triggers etc.)

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO foobar(foo, bar) VALUES ('FOO', 'BAR');
EXECPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'Could not handle your request.');
END;
```

But this obviously requires PL/SQL code around the statements that potentially cause exceptions. AFAIK there is no way to globally intercept all exceptions from individual SQL statements.